# Prove $\epsilon(S\cap T)\subseteq S \cap T$

Tags: automata, finite-automata, check-my-answer

> Suppose there are sets $S\subseteq Q, T\subseteq Q$ such that $T=\epsilon (T),S=\epsilon (S)$.
>
> Prove $\epsilon(S\cap T)\subseteq S \cap T$

Definition of $\epsilon$- closure for epsilon NFA is:

> $\epsilon : 2^Q \rightarrow 2^Q $
>
> a) $S \subseteq \epsilon (S)$ Base case
>
> b) If $q \in \epsilon (S)$ then $\delta(q,\epsilon )\subseteq \epsilon (S)$ Recursive case
>
> c) and nothing else is in $\epsilon (S)$
>
> And also, S is a set of all states in epsilon-NFA.

My proof:

Is this a correct reasoning?

[image: Epsilon NFA example]

Comment: I don’t understand your reasoning. Try instead to use the definitions.

Comment: I included a picture with an example hopefully it clarifies.

Comment: A picture is not a proof.

Comment: The sets $S,T$ could definitely have outgoing $\epsilon$-transitions.

Comment: They could but we stated that $S=\epsilon (S)$ and $T=\epsilon (T)$, so they don't have epsilon transitions

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/).

Comment: Yeah I am looking for possible guidance of the possible proof also.

Comment: The sets $S,T$ could have outgoing epsilon transitions, as long as they stay within the sets.

Comment: As I explained in my answer to your [previous question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/115839/let-m-be-an-epsilon-nfa-and-let-s-subseteq-q-prove-epsilon-s-epsilo), you can't really prove anything using your "definition" of epsilon closure.

Answer (score 2):

Since your definition of $\epsilon$-closure isn't really a definition, it is impossible to prove anything using it. Instead, let me use the following definition: the $\epsilon$-closure of a set $S \subseteq Q$ consists of all states $x \in Q$ which are reachable from a state in $S$ by a (possibly empty) $\epsilon$-path (which is a path consisting of $\epsilon$-transitions).

Suppose that $\epsilon(S) = S$ and $\epsilon(T) = T$, and let $q \in \epsilon(S \cap T)$. Thus $q$ is reachable by a state $r \in S \cap T$ via an $\epsilon$-path. Since $r \in S \cap T$, in particular $r \in S$, and so, by definition, $q \in \epsilon(S) = S$. Similarly, $q \in \epsilon(T) = T$. Therefore $q \in S \cap T$.